# Why use stateless session beans for transaction demarcation

Tags: jakarta-ee, transactions, ejb, cdi

I frequently find myself converting an @AppplicationScoped bean into a SLSB bean just so that i can use @TransactionalAttribute.

What are the advantages of doing this over creating a custom CDI interceptor to begin and end transactions that i can use on any bean?

Comment: Apache DeltaSpike does just that, I wouldn't be surprised if it eventually makes it into the CDI spec.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is already implementation of `@Transactional` in new CDI spec which came together with Java EE 7, so you can apply it to all Managed Beans in your application and it works the same way as the `@TransactionalAttribute` did. Check the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/transaction/Transactional.html) for more info.

**CDI vs EJB**

Difference is quite easy, always use `CDI` if you don't need things like scheduling, remote beans, asynchronous behaviour or security. See any kind of tutorial for what are these features and how to implement them. Also note that if you use `CDI` then every class in your application will effectively turn in `Managed Bean` including EJB beans.

Comment: That is very interesting but it doesn't specify the advantages of using an SLSB over a managed bean.

Comment: SLSB and CDI beans are managed by the container. The services could be different but the lifecycle is always managed.

Answer (score 0):

EJB will become an specialized set of services provided by the cdi container.

So, to resolve your question: 
EJBs by default are capable of some things where cdi dont:

- Timers
- Asynchronous, transactional execution with Future support
- Pooling: important for throttling and prevention of denial of service attacks
- Monitoring - all EJBs are exposed via JMX and can be so monitored with JConsole
- Declarative, "Convention Over Configuration" transactions. Without EJB 3 you will end up in a considerable bloat.

So, if you are only using the transactional aspect, well, there is no really big difference between a cdi+interceptor or a EJB.

source: http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/cdi_with_or_without_ejb